# A Bigger Random Number After Refreshing Page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm using some javascript in my new web project. I need too generate a random number. But it's a little different !

The code should generate a bigger random number after any refresh !

Fore example :

- First it gives : `1000`
- After refresh : `2000`
- Another refresh : `4302`
- And `...`

I mean the code should never give us, any repeated number and after every single refresh, the number must be bigger than the last !

Is there any method for javascript?! Or I need to use other things like PHP or ...
If yes, How ?!

Comment: What's the range of your intervals?

Comment: You do *know* what random means, right?

Comment: just change the lower limit to the previous number and the upper limit to the previous number + the interval

Comment: Do you have a method of storing what the number was before the refresh?  Cookies, etc?

Comment: "a bigger random number after any refresh" means every refresh made by the same client? Same logged in user? Every request made to the server?

Comment: You are expected to **try to write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 2):

use `new Date().valueOf()` (representing the current timestramp in milliseconds) it will be always bigger than the previous because it is unidirectional

Comment: But it's not random, it's the current time in MS

Comment: what is you purpose? I guess its to jump the cache right?

Comment: I haven't given it much thought actually, but someone obviously thinks that your suggestion is valid and i'm not going to DV your answer, as the OP didn't explain their requirement clearly and didn't provide a [mcve]

Comment: Oho, my bad, in the first comment I just thought you are the OP, hehe, sorry for that. yeah, its not random, but again random doesn't meant it will maintain some criteria, and also OP dosen't provided any detail so just thought that it might be  for jumping the cache or just need a number greater than the previous one (obviously if dosen't bother with what its matching). If you still think its downvote-worthy (logically shouldn't be the case)  you can do that :)

Comment: Thanks, but as I said before - I'm **not** going to DV your answer, but I'm not going to Upvote it either though :)

Comment: How can I use it?!

Comment: Even I want to know, once you have the number, how you want to use that? if your question was about how you will get that just assign it to a javascript variable, and you will get a number always bigger than the previous.

Answer (score 1):

You could accomplish that this using a PHP session (since you have included PHP in your tag, I'm assuming this is OK), and then set it as a global JS variable that you can access:

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['random_number'])) {
        $_SESSION['random_number'] += rand();
    } else {
        $_SESSION['random_number'] = rand();
    }
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var random_number = <?php echo $_SESSION['random_number']; ?>;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP, you can store it in a session. Then just generate a random number with the `rand()` function, using `min` parameter to ensure you get a higher number each refresh. Passing the `PHP_INT_MAX` constant to the `max` parameter, you will get a "highest" possible number the PHP engine can handle.

By adding `$_SESSION['random_integer'] + 1` to `min` if the session is set already, we guarantee that the next random number will be higher than the current one. If it's not set, we just define it to be zero.

```
session_start();
$min_value = !isset($_SESSION['random_integer'] ? 1 : $_SESSION['random_integer'] + 1;
$_SESSION['random_integer'] = rand($min_value, PHP_INT_MAX);
echo $_SESSION['random_integer'];
```

`PHP_INT_MAX` will differ from 32 and 64 bit systems, but it should be sufficiently high enough.

- [PHP manual on `rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php)